# Can the restund server be hosted alongside my dedicated hosting server?

Tags: apache, http, webrtc

I want to implement a restund server for WebRTC audio on my website. I wish to have one user be able to talk to all the other users on the platform (if anyone knows an easier way to do this than implementing a restund WebRTC server, please let me know, would help me out a lot).

But before I go and try to get restund working, I was wondering if it could be installed to work alongside my Apache HTTP dedicated server I use to host my website.

Answer (score 0):

Well, STUN/TURN services are running on ports 3478 and 5349 by default. That should not conflict with those required for HTTP operations (e.g. 80, 443, 8080). So yes, this should be possible.

Comment: For some rare cases, it is interesting to allow the TURN server to be reached on port 443 over TLS (TURNS). Like that, you can bypass a proxy/Firewall and make a WebRTC call even with the proxy/FW only allows HTTP and HTTPS.